# PHP If Statements With mySQL Results

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

The code below is supposed to check if there is a person in the database with a row in the database with the username it gets from the cookie login.And if there is it is supposed to include a page and if there isn't a person in the database with this user_id it is supposed to echo.Here is my code so far please tell me how I would do this.I also already know before someone tells me that mySQL statements like I have it are becoming depreciated.Here is My code:

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
mysql_select_db("maxgee_close2");
$username = $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user']; 
$result = mysql_query("select user_id from users where username = '$username'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);    
mysql_free_result($result);
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events_main WHERE user_id ='$row['user_id']'") or die(mysql_error());
if(1==1){
  if (mysql_num_rows($check)>0) 
 {
include("example.php");
 }
  else
  {
  echo "example";
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: You're open to SQL injection.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Inside the double quoted SQL string, you should either _not_ quote the array key `user_id`, or better, wrap the whole thing in `{}` as in `user_id ='{$row['user_id']}'` Otherwise, your variable parsing is going to break at the first quote of the array key, breaking your SQL statement.

Comment: @alfasin I know I already said that above

Comment: At a minimum you _MUST_ call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$username`.  Cookie values are not safe.

Comment: @WaleedKhan he uses magic quotes to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski he uses magic quotes to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: *he uses magic quotes to prevent SQL injection*, really?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I changed $username it is now: mysql_real_escape_string($username = $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user']);

Comment: @maxgee Almost:  `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user']);`

Comment: @maxgee Ok - I'll put in an answer about your quoting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the double-quoted string, your array variable `$row['user_id']` is being incorrectly parsed due to the fact that you have quoted the array key without surrounding the whole thing in `{}`. It is permissible to omit the `{}` in a double-quoted string if you *don't quote the array key*, but the `{}` adds readability.

```
check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events_main WHERE user_id ='{$row['user_id']}'") or die(mysql_error());
//-------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// Also acceptable, but not as tidy, and troublesome with multidimensional 
// or variable keys - unquoted array key
check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events_main WHERE user_id ='$row[user_id]'") or die(mysql_error());
//-------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As mentioned above, `$_COOKIE` is never considered a safe value. You must escape its values against SQL injection if you continue to use the old `mysql_*()` API:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user']);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 Things right off the bat, like Waleed said you're open to SQL injection, not very nice thing to have happen to you.  I would look into reading tutorials about MySQLi and PDOs, from there try and dive into a better way or running queries.

Also you are choosing to use cookies instead of sessions to store the username?  Cookies can be modified client-side to say anything a smart user with firebug would want them to be.  Sessions are stored server-side and the client (end-user) is only given an id of the session.  They cannot modify the username if you send it as a session. (They could try and change the session id to another random bunch of numbers but thats like pissing into the wind, pardon my french.

Heres some pseduo code that will get you on your way I think

```
<?php
 include("dbconnect.php");

 $database = "maxgee_close2"; //Set the database you want to connect to

 mysql_select_db($database); //Select database

 $username = $_SESSION['maxgee_me_user']; //Grab the username from a server-side stored session, not a cookie!

 $query = "SELECT user_id FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "' LIMIT 1"; //Note the user of mysql_real_escape_string on the $username, we want to clean the variable of anything that could harm the database.

 $result = mysql_query($query);

 if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  //Query was ran and returned a result, grab the ID
  $userId = $row["user_id"];

  mysql_free_result($result); //We can free the result now after we have grabbed everything we need

  $query_check = "SELECT * FROM `events_main` WHERE `user_id` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($userId) . "'";

  $check = mysql_query($query_check);
   if (mysql_num_rows($check)>0) {
    include("example.php");
   }
   else {
    echo "example";
   }
 }

 ?>
```

That code may/may not work but the real key change is that fact that you were running 
    mysql_free_result($result);
before your script had a chance to grab the user id from the database.

All in all, I would really go back and read some more tutorials.

Comment: I would use sessions if I unserstood them...Once I get my websites foundation set up where it will work I am planning on doing it with sessions instead and using PDO's what I have right now is just temporary to think about how I am gonnna make it work and then after I get it to work i am gonna make it work its best without security problems.